# How to build an executable jar in java

Tags: java

I am following some guide to build an executable jar.
But I am having a problem, A Java Exception occured.
I tried to run it in cmd.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lc.kra.system.keyboard.GlobalKeyboardHook

I am using 4 external libraries.
mindrot jbcrypt,json simple, geoip2, and keyboard and mouse hook

My Jar file directories are,
[image]

here is my imports,

```
package timer_app;
...
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
import lc.kra.system.keyboard.GlobalKeyboardHook;
import lc.kra.system.keyboard.event.GlobalKeyAdapter;
import lc.kra.system.keyboard.event.GlobalKeyEvent;
import lc.kra.system.mouse.GlobalMouseHook;
import lc.kra.system.mouse.event.GlobalMouseAdapter;
import lc.kra.system.mouse.event.GlobalMouseEvent;
import org.json.simple.JSONAware;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.*;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

and here is my Manifest file,

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_101 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: timer_app.Timer
Class-Path: lib\lib1.jar lib\geoip2-2.8.0-rc1.jar lib\system-hook-2.5.jar
```

Added cReate jar tool in jcreator.
[image]

Comment: How did you create the runnable jar? Did you use Eclipse? If yes, can you show a snapshot of your build path?

Comment: JCreator. I added new image for Create Jar Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `lib1.jar`, `geoip2-2.8.0-rc1.jar` and `system-hook-2.5.jar` into your lib sub-directory or modify your manifest-file manually to remove the leading `lib\` from the path.

Answer (score 0):

jars inside a jar will not be added to the classpath. You have to unjar the thirt Party jars and add the classes only.

Comment: so how can i do it? when i tried only the other 3 jars. it is working. when i added Globalkeyboard and globalmouse hooks, there is an error.